# Logical grouped bar graph

Tags: r, bar-chart

I want two bars for each day of the week -- one for presence of behavior (logical > 0) and one for absence of behavior ( == 0) according to my data.

Right now I'm using the following, but it is graphing a single bar, which takes into account the zeros in my data. Would like to do this grouped bar as simply as possible (or without much modification to current code)

```
Data$weekday <- factor(Data$weekday, levels= c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday","Saturday"))
y <- by(Data$Variable, EMA$weekday, mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
barplot(y, main = "title", ylab = "axis label")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: `y <- by(Data$Variable, interaction(EMA$weekday, Data$behaviour), mean, na.rm = TRUE)`